# Ignore peer dependency check for single package in package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, peer-dependencies

I try to exclude the package **react-virtualized** from the peer dependency checking of NPM 7. I know I could separately install that package with

`npm install react-virtualized --legacy-peer-deps`

...but my goal is to install all packages with npm install and this one shall not be checked for peer dependencies. Is that possible?

I would accept any answer that shows me how to manipulate the package.json so that a fresh **npm install** runs without peer dependency errors.
I have the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.11.14",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.0",
    "react-resize-detector": "^6.7.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3"
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `npm install` and not include any flags? (Asking because it affects the viability of potential solutions, like requiring a particular version of npm.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `npm@>=8.3.0` use overrides in `package.json`:

```json
"overrides": {
  "react-virtualized": {
    "react": "$react",
    "react-dom": "$react-dom"
  }
}
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to do that within your own `package.json` as far as I am aware. The change would need to happen in the `package.json` for the `react-virtualized` package. Perhaps one of these alternatives will work for you:

1. Set [legacy-peer-deps in a .npmrc file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps) for your project. This won't work if people are installing your project via `npm` but if your project is cloned from a git repository or otherwise downloaded, and then people run `npm install` from there, including a `.npmrc` in the project should work.
2. Require using `npm@6` which will be more lenient about peer dependency checks. You can specify the `npm` version in [the "engines" field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) in your `package.json`.
3. Install `react-virtualized` from GitHub. The master branch (and, as of this writing, unfortunately only the master branch) has the d36509817ac44 commit which added `react@17` and `react-dom@17` as acceptable peer dependencies. Because this code is not in any release yet, you may be getting a version of the module that is unstable. To do this: `npm install git+https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized.git`
4. Use `react@16` and `react-dom@16` instead of `@17` for each.